# Callback after all switch branches are done in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple function in node.js with switch in for loop:

```
function bodybuilder(queryArea,callback)
{
    var ret='';
    for (var attributename in queryArea.query)
        {
                switch(attributename)
                {
                    case 'username':
                    {
                        ret+="Username branch added";
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'what':
                    {
                                filename="./demo.html";
                                fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data)
                                        {if (err) throw(err);
                                        var pom=data.toString();
                                        ret=ret+pom;
                                        });
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'color':
                    {
                        ret+="Color branch added";
                    }
                    break;
                    default: ret+="Unknown query";
                }
        }
    return callback(ret);
}
```

Every switch branch is accessed and adds something to return value.

One of the branches reads asynchronously file and adds its content to return value.

How to callback on this whole function and return value after ALL switch branches are done? This means, after even the async operation of processing the file is done? Node is not waiting for that obviously.

It's a learning example, so showing principle on this would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an asynchronous code inside a for loop, you need to call callback function from the asynchronous switch case as it will be executed after whole for loop has been executed.

Use below code snippet for the same:

```
function bodybuilder(queryArea,callback)
{
   var ret='';
   for (var attributename in queryArea.query)
      {
            switch(attributename)
            {
                case 'username':
                {
                    ret+="Username branch added";
                }
                break;
                case 'what':
                {
                            filename="./demo.html";
                            fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data)
                                    {if (err) throw(err);
                                    var pom=data.toString();
                                    ret=ret+pom;
                                    callback(ret); 
                             });
                }
                break;
                case 'color':
                {
                    ret+="Color branch added";
                }
                break;
                default: ret+="Unknown query";
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. To keep it as general as possible - how to ensure this functionality if you don't know which branch will be the slowest? If you had for example readFile in two branches?

Comment: Keep the counter maintained for all the asynchronous calls and in callback of all the asynchronous calls check for counter `if(counter==<number of aync calls>)` and if true then call the callback function of entire function.

Comment: Really great and understandable answer. Accepting and thank you